# Implements OnClickListener in cardview to get specific data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With the code I have currently, I get to retrieve every attendance details [image 3] when Onclick on any cardview[image 2].

Now, I hope to get the specific data in each cardview.

Flow: **userlist.java** [implements OnClickListener here]-> **userlist1.java**

Hoping results:

CardView 1 [info:test3] ->  1 Attendance  (MdkeONsLFaBK9DgyKMu)

CardView 2 [info:rea] -> 2 Attendance  (Mdkf_TBTWI4D6yRyGLa) & (Mdkfbbtb2mRUZXEIwdr)

**userlist.class**

```
public class userlist extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference database, ab;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<Report> list;
    String uid;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    Menu menu;
    private SearchView searchView = null;
    private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist);

        user = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userlist);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.action_search);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
        String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("temp","");


        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Class Information");
        ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend");

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        ab.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Report report = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report.class);
                    list.add(report);

                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_dateascending:
                Collections.sort(list, Report.ReportDateOldestComparator);
                Toast.makeText(userlist.this, "Sort by Date [Oldest - Latest]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_descending:
                Collections.sort(list, Report.ReportDateLatestComparator);
                Toast.makeText(userlist.this, "Sort by Date [Latest - Oldest]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:
                // Not implemented here
                return false;
            default:
                break;
        }
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>implements Filterable {


    Context context;
    ArrayList<Report> list;
    ArrayList<Report> listfilter;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Report> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listfilter = list;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Report report = list.get(position);
        holder.time.setText(report.getTime());
        holder.duration.setText(report.getDuration());
        holder.info.setText(report.getInfo());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    list = listfilter;
                } else {
                    List<Report> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Report row : listfilter) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getInfo().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getTime().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }
                    list = (ArrayList<Report>) filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = list;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                list = (ArrayList<Report>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { 

        TextView duration, time, info;
        public View view;
        String key, temp;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtemp);
            duration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfirstName);
            info = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmatno);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
            String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("temp","");

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View itemView) {

                    sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("key", key);
                    editor.putString("temp", temp);
                    editor.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), userlist1.class);
                    itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);// pass key to next activity;

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Data retrieved from database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Report.java**

```
public class Report {

    public String duration;
    public String time;
    public String info;

    public Report(){

    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }


    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public static Comparator<Report> ReportDateOldestComparator = new Comparator<Report>() {
        @Override

        public int compare(Report o1, Report o2) {
            return o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime());

        }
    };

    public static Comparator<Report> ReportDateLatestComparator = new Comparator<Report>() {
        @Override

        public int compare(Report o1, Report o2) {
            return o2.getTime().compareTo(o1.getTime());

        }
    };
}
```

**userlist1.java**

```
public class userlist1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference database,ab;
    MyAdapter1 myAdapter1;
    ArrayList<Report1> list;
    String uid;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist1);

        user = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userlist1);


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
        String temp = sharedPreferences.getString("temp","");
        String abc = sharedPreferences.getString("abc","");


        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Class Information");
        ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend");
        //ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend").child(key).child("Attendance");
        //ab = database.child(uid).child("Student Attend").child("test").child(key);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        //ArrayList<Report1> list = new ArrayList<Report1>();
        myAdapter1 = new MyAdapter1(this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter1);


        ab.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    /*List<Report1>list = new ArrayList<>();*/
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : childSnapshot.child("Attendance").getChildren()) {


                        Report1 report1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Report1.class);
                        list.add(report1);
                    }
                }
           myAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter1.java**

```
public class MyAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Report1> list;

    public MyAdapter1(Context context, ArrayList<Report1> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item1,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Report1 report1 = list.get(position);
        holder.matricno.setText(report1.getMatricno());
        holder.password.setText(report1.getPassword());
        holder.temp.setText(report1.getTemp());
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{ //public static class

        TextView matricno, password, temp;
        public View view;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            matricno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmno);
            password = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvpassword);
            temp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtemperature);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View itemView) {

                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Data retrieved from database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Report1.java**

```
public class Report1 {
    public String matricno;
    public String password;
    public String temp;

public Report1(){
}

    public String getMatricno() {
        return matricno;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }
    public void setMatricno(String matricno) {
        this.matricno = matricno;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new **Activity**, Get the `position` of the Item. Pass the data via `Intent`.

```
holder.myItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View itemView) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewItemDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra(“yourKey1”, value1);
                    intent.putExtra(“yourKey2”, value2);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```